# Как можно подключиться к существующей БД используя командную строку и создать новую схему?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Задача такая:

имеется база - **name_base**
пользователь - **user**
пароль - **password**

База находится на удаленной системе, вот настройки подключения

```java
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//SRV01:1521/sid_name
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
```

У меня есть в Spring boot тесты.

Я хотел бы создать новую схему в данной базе.
Но для этого нужно создать:
 - нового пользователя, дать ему права (наверное)
 - база данных будет находится на том-же хосте, по такому же порту, но
нужено ли задавть новый sid (.../sid_name)?
 - создать схему (то есть таблицы один в один как в оригинальной базе, например схему можно как-то создать, сделав выгрузку из существующей рабочей схемы)
- все эти команды (создание пользователя, импорт схемы) нужно сделать в скрипте

об **oracle** мало что знаю, кто может подскажите как создать все это

Мне нужен скрипт, который выполнит эти задачи, а я его укажу в качестве импорта в своих тестах.

**Дополнение**

У меня есть имя пользователя и пароль, с помощью которого я подключаюсь из среды разработки к существующей базе данных.
Могу создавать таблицы, могу удалять, добавлять данные и редактировать.

Например, из существующей базы я хотел бы сделать дамп базы (как это сделать не знаю), оставляю в каждой из таблиц до 10 строк ( таблицы имеют связи) и создаю новой табличное пространство под новым пользователем и паролем - это все один скрипт который я затем импортирую в класс, который у меня является точкой входа на запуск интеграционных тестов.

Если нельзя при выгрузки схемы удалить данные ( то есть оставить до 10 строк), тогда хотя бы структуру таблиц выгрузить в новую схему.

У нас из нет **Db-администраторов**, никто у нас не смог мне подсказать как выполнить поставленную задачу.
 можно ли из sql-developer (или какие есть бесплатные аналоги для администрирования базы) подлкючиться и создавать нужных пользователей и назначать роли и системные привелегии ?

Мне поставили задачу найти сведения, какие роли нужно задать новому пользователю, который будет иметь возможность выполнять выше поставленные задачи.

В sql-developer я нашел как создать нового пользователя:

-name_base/other_user , затем команда - CREATE USER

Но ему нужны права такие, чтобы он мог создавать свои табличные пространства и **не смог удалить другие или как-то их редактировать**.

У кого есть какие идеи ?

Comment: А какие у вас есть права в БД, например создать нового пользователя можете? Самоё простое сделать экспорт схемы и импорт в новую схему.

Comment: У вас недостаточно прав для поставленной задачи. Обратитесь к вашим DBA, они вам помогут.

Comment: PPS Одно из двух - или у вас есть пароль пользователя system, или есть кто-то, у кого есть этот пароль. Как вполнить задачу, я уже написал комментарием выше.

Comment: я выше указал, что я могу сам создать этого пользователя, через sql-developer, но какие права нужно ему дать ?

Comment: Выглядит так, то вроде все пункты из вопроса отвечены (может ошибаюсь). Добавте пожалуйста в вопрос, почему не удалось решить задачу?

Answer (score 3):

Сделайте экспорт существующей схемы и импортируйте с созданием новой схемы.

Дамп БД и лог к нему будет создан на системе, где установлена БД, по умолчанию, в уже созданом каталоге `data_pump_dir`.

```
$ expdp system/pass@dbserver/service_name \
    schemas=user1 directory=data_pump_dir dumpfile=exp_user1_meta.dmp content=metadata_only
```

С параметром `content=metadata_only` будут созданы только пустые таблицы.

```
$ impdp system/pass@dbserver/service_name \
    directory=data_pump_dir dumpfile=exp_user1_meta.dmp remap_schema=user1:user2
```

С параметром `remap_schema=user1:user2` будет создан новый пользователь `user2`, который унаследует все объекты БД и привилегии от пользователя `user1`.

Новый пользователь создаётся с одноразовым паролем. Измените ему пароль и можете начинать с ним работать:

```
$ sqlplus system/pass@dbserver/service_name
SQL> alter user user2 identified by user2;
SQL> connect user2/user2@dbserver/service_name
Connected.
```